# Selecting records with the most recent date for each unique identifier

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-office

To start, I've been scouring the internet for the last four hours and have come across a few similar issues (most here on stack overflow) with solutions that look like they could work, but did not (most of them used a single table).

I have two tables - Personnel and Tests. Personnel contains information about each person indexed by SSN. Such as:

```
ID   SSN          PersonName
101  111-11-1111  Joe
102  222-22-2222  Bob
103  333-33-3333  Jebadiah
```

Tests is a table that contains information about tests each person has taken. These tests are related to the Personnel table by SSN. Each person can have any number of tests:

```
ID   SSN          TestDate  Score
201  111-11-1111  1/1/2013  95.7
202  111-11-1111  2/7/2013  75.2
203  222-22-2222  1/9/2013  85.6
204  333-33-3333  5/6/2013  79.9
205  333-33-3333  4/8/2013  88.8
```

What I need to do is select the most recent test date and score for each person. I'm looking for a resultset that looks like this:

```
SSN          PersonName  TestDate  Score
111-11-1111  Joe         2/7/2013  75.2
222-22-2222  Bob         1/9/2013  85.6
333-33-3333  Jebadiah    5/6/2013  79.9
```

I've been trying a lot of joins and such, but I can't seem to get it to retrieve only ONE record for each SSN AND select the fields I want. Everything will select either every test and the fields I want or one test but only the SSN.

I'm hoping it's a simple solution that will make me smack my forehead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.SSN, a.PersonName, b.TestDate, b.Score
FROM    ((Personnel AS a
        INNER JOIN Tests AS b
            ON a.SSN = b.SSN)
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  SSN, MAX(TestDate) AS MAX_DATE
            FROM    Tests 
            GROUP   BY SSN
        ) AS c  ON  b.SSN = c.SSN AND
                b.TestDate = c.MAX_DATE)
```

**UPDATE 1**

There are many ways to solve this problem but the solution I'm used to do is like this. Normally, the join between `Personnel` and `Test` will give all records but that's not exactly what you want. So I joined it with a subquery which gets the latest `TestDate` for every `SSN` and the result of the subquery is then joined back on the two tables provided that it matched on two conditions: `SSN` and `TestDate`.

Comment: This appears to work EXACTLY as I need it to. Thank you! I must admit, however, that I am a little confused as to what exactly is happening here.